# Electric field intensity $E$

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, intensity

Electric field intensity (**E**) is defined as the electrostatic force experienced by a unit positive charge , mathematically **E** = **F**/**q**,it seems like the mathematical equation **E** = **F**/**q** contradicts the definition of **E**, because **E**(electrostatic force experienced by a unit positive charge **q**) can be written as **kQq/r^2 or Qq/4πĒ•r^2** ,(Q is the source charge and Ē• is permittivity of medium) then why **E** = **F**(electrostatic force experienced by**q**) /**q** , it's also dimensionally incorrect ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electric field (or electric field intensity) is *not* the electrostatic force experienced by a unit charge. As you pointed out, they are not dimensionally equal. In fact, the electric field intensity is given by $$E = k_e\frac{Q}{r^2}$$ and the electrostatic force between two stationary point charges $Q$ and $q$ is $$F_e = k_e\frac{|Q|.|q|}{r^2}$$ If you substitute $q = 1C$, you will find that the values of $F_e$ and $E$ are only **numerically** equal: $$|F_e| = k_e\frac{Q.(1C)}{r^2} = E .(1C) $$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only contradiction is the way you have asked the question. The force exerted by charge $Q$ on charge $q$ at a distance $r$ from it is given by
$$F = k \frac{q\, Q}{r^2}.$$ The electric field $E$ of $Q$ is the force experienced by a **unit** positive charge, i.e. $q = 1\, C$. A unit charge means its magnitude is unity or 1.

Equivalently, the field can be worked out by dividing $F$ by $q$ where now the $q$ is not necessarily $1$. Whichever approach is taken, $$E = k \frac{Q}{r^2},$$ which is exactly what the definition is.